# Questions regarding ingredients specified in recipe

Tags: extract, grain, extract-brewing

I was interested in brewing [this](https://byo.com/fruit-beer/item/1184-northern-india-pale-ale) recipe but I have a couple of questions regarding the grain used.

```
0.5 lb. crystal malt, 50° Lovibond
0.5 lb. toasted malt, 25° Lovibond
```

Does this refer to crushed grain because it's an extract brew?

For the toasted malt - would [this](https://www.thehomebrewcompany.ie/biscuit-whole-brewferm-ebc-50-1kg-p-2109.html) be a good substitute?

> Available at last: the real Belgian BISCUIT malt. This very
>   light-roasted malt with only 50 EBC of colour, gives a biscuit/bread
>   aroma to your beer. Use 5-15%.

Also it says:

> 6 lbs. gold light malt extract

Does this refer to plain old light malt extract? The [site](https://www.thehomebrewcompany.ie/ingredientsadditivessteriliser-liquid-malt-extract-c-3_38.html) I order off doesn't seem to have specifically "gold light".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those old Brew Your Own recipes are a little vague on ingredients, and hard to figure out.  You have an added handicap of being in the Eurozone, it seems.

Likely the 3.3 bs. of amber light extract is LME (because in the U.S. they sell it in 3.3 lb. cans and plastic milk jugs), and you can substitute a 1.5 kg can of Coopers Light Malt Extract or the Premium Light. My guess is that the 6.0 lbs. of gold light extract is also LME (rather than what you call spray malt and we call DME) because U.S. recipes usually do not use so much DME. - I would go with Coopers Amber Malt Extract.

The grains are going to have to be crushed -- you will steep them in hot water as per the recipe, and then remove them before adding your malt extracts.

For toasted malt, this is going to be similar to "victory malt" or this ["biscuit malt/amber malt"](https://www.thehomebrewcompany.ie/biscuit-malt-crushed-grains-500g-brewferm-p-153.html). If you can't get it, you can make it at home by using WHOLE pale malt and toasting it in your oven at 350°F/175°C for 10-15 minutes. You will need to store it in a brown paper bag for two weeks to allow the harsh bitterness from kilning to mellow.  Crush it with a rolling pin until husks are separated and vast majority of grains are broken into bits (and a little bit of flour is OK) before using.

Slainte!

Comment: Cheers for the info :)